# Forward a FTP port via UPnP in Python

Tags: python, ftp, network-programming, debian, raspbian

I am making a Python application that requires the server to have an FTP port forwarded to his computer(a Rasberry PI3) in order to communicate with client. The current implementation works quite great, yet the only thing is that the person who's running the file must forward the port to the local IP manually. I want to automate this. I have serached a lot but i didnt find anything.

Comment: Please put the command to forward the port into the question. Is your program running on the system that needs to forward the port? Or, are you trying to find a way for the client to make the server forward a port?

Comment: Im trying to find a way to automate the port forwarding mechanism, because now i have manually to go in the router port forwarding page and i have to manually insert the port and ip. I need a python code to automate that

Comment: Is your first question, "What is the route command to forward a port?" After getting that, it can be run from Python.

Comment: But i cant also find that command, i only know that exist some libraries that use upnp to forward port but i don't know how to use it

Comment: You might want an iptables command. https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables This question might be better asked on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot, and now you can import this code in python for the 20 and 21 port?

Comment: I think that your link concern to a local ip table not to the router ip table..